# Breaking change in RxJs ErrorObservable (Migration 5 -> 6)

Tags: typescript, rxjs5, rxjs6

We're facing an issue while updating our application to RxJs 6 (with rxjs-compat). 
A referenced library, which is still on RxJs 5 is using ErrorObservable as a return type of a method.

```
public handleError(error: Error): ErrorObservable {
    ...
    return Observable.throw('some error message');
}
```

As of now ErrorObservable is a non-generic type in RxJs:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.11/src/observable/ErrorObservable.ts

```
export class ErrorObservable extends Observable<any> {
  ...
}
```

This has changed with RxJs 6
(see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/compat/observable/ErrorObservable.ts)

```
export class ErrorObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {
  static create<T>(error: any, scheduler?: SchedulerLike) {
    return throwError(error, scheduler);
  }
}
```

Which of course leads to a compile error:

```
ERROR in ... : error TS2314: Generic type 'ErrorObservable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

Is this a case, which is not covered by `rxjs-compat` or is it an issue with the type definition in `rxjs-compat`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look into [breaking-changes section](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#breaking-changes)

> All observable classes
>   (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/5.5.8/src/observable) have
>   been removed from v6, in favor of existing or new operators that
>   perform the same operations as the class methods. For example,
>   `ArrayObservable.create(myArray)` can be replaced by `from(myArray)`, or
>   the new operator `fromArray()`

It seems you should use `throwError` function instead of `ErrorObservable` class.